# Como faco para ler e armazenar o dados da resposta de uma API?

Tags: php, json

Consegui a resposta da `API` da `CIELO` abaixo, agora gostaria de entender com faço para ler e armazenar os valores.

Se alguém puder me ajudar com quais as principais informações devo armazenar no  banco de dados?

> `object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["MerchantOrderId"]=> string(16)     "2014113245231706" ["Customer"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["Name"]=>     string(24) "Comprador rec programada" } ["Payment"]=> object(stdClass)#4    (15) { ["ServiceTaxAmount"]=> int(0) ["Installments"]=> int(1) ["Interest"]=> int(0) ["Capture"]=> bool(false) ["Authenticate"]=> bool(false) ["Recurrent"]=> bool(false) ["CreditCard"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (5) { ["CardNumber"]=> string(16) "123412******1231" ["Holder"]=> string(12) "Teste Holder" ["ExpirationDate"]=> string(7) "03/2019" ["SaveCard"]=> bool(false) ["Brand"]=> string(4) "Visa" } ["SoftDescriptor"]=> string(13) "123456789ABCD" ["Provider"]=> string(8) "Simulado" ["Type"]=> string(10) "CreditCard" ["Amount"]=> int(1500) ["Currency"]=> string(3) "BRL" ["Country"]=> string(3) "BRA" ["Status"]=> int(20) ["RecurrentPayment"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (9) { ["RecurrentPaymentId"]=> string(36) "85717927-b438-461b-908f-764772289cb5" ["ReasonCode"]=> int(0) ["ReasonMessage"]=> string(10) "Successful" ["NextRecurrency"]=> string(10) "2015-06-01" ["StartDate"]=> string(10) "2015-06-01" ["EndDate"]=> string(10) "2019-12-01" ["Interval"]=> int(6) ["Link"]=> object(stdClass)#7 (3) { ["Method"]=> string(3) "GET" ["Rel"]=> string(16) "recurrentPayment" ["Href"]=> string(107) "https://apiquerysandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/1/RecurrentPayment/8 5717927-b438-461b-908f-764772289cb5" } ["AuthorizeNow"]=> bool(false) } }    }`

Answer (score -2):

Eles te retornaram um JSON, ao que parece.
Você lê os dados como um objeto normal. Por exemplo:

`<?php
echo $objeto->MerchantOrderId; // output: 2014113245231706`

Para salvar, depende do que você está utilizando para persistência e o que vai fazer com essas informações. Mas no geral pode salvar normalmente como qualquer outra informação. Exemplos:

- Salvar num banco relacional, mapeando as propriedades deste objeto para colunas em alguma tabela ou ainda salvando o json inteiro (usando `json_encode($objeto)`, que retorna uma string;
- Salvar num banco não-relacional, como mongo ou couchdb;
- Salvar em arquivo `file_put_contents("arquivo.json", json_encode($objeto));

Cabe a você definir como quer salvar estes dados.

Comment: Muito obrigado! E se eu quiser a informação mapeada abaixo: ["Payment"]["RecurrentPayment"]["StartDate"]=> string(10) "2015-06-01", como faço ?

Comment: Poderia colar o JSON assim como aparece na API?

Comment: Algo do tipo funcionaria ?                                                                                  
    $xmlString = "my.xml";
    $xmlObject = simplexml_load_file($xmlString);
    $xmltovar = json_decode(json_encode($xmlObject), true);


    foreach($xmltovar ["Payment"] as $test) {

         echo $test["RecurrentPayment"]["StartDate"]."<br>";
       
}